# how to horizontally align a centered ul

Tags: html, css, navigation, alignment, html-lists

I have a `ul` centered to the screen but the list items get displayed 1 by 1 vertically and I'd like to have them displayed horizontally. This is the code:

```
<nav style="margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
    <ul style="list-style: none; display: inline;">
        <li><a href=""> obj1</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> obj2</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> obj3</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> obj4</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> obj5</a></li>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` to your ul and it will work

```
<nav style="margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
    <ul style="list-style: none; display: flex; flex-direction: row">
        <li><a href=""> obj1</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> obj2</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> obj3</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> obj4</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> obj5</a></li>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried and the items get displayed horizontally, but they aren't centered anymore and don't have spaces between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your list items displayed horizontally by applying `display: inline` to your list items directly. Here's the CSS for it:

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change display: inline; to display: inline-flex;